# can we use netcat to communicate between 2 computers in the same network

Tags: networking, udp, communication, netcat

I would like to communicate between two machines on the same network by using netcat. Basically I need to send some UDP frames from one machine to another on the same network. 
I looked through netcat literature and found it is possible to send UDP frames, so first i tried between 2 Linux consoles on the same machine.
Next, I tried between 2 machines on the same network but this did not work. 
Can someone please explain how can this be done or if there is some alternate method that can be used.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your firewalls allow UDP throughput.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi cantelope thanks a lot for that information, actually Iam trying to send UDP frames within the same network and there is no firewall set internally as checked by my network admin.

Comment: However out of curiosity I would like to know where can we add this above command. Thanks a lot for the response!!

Comment: iptables is a firewall program in debain linux. You use it from the command line. You can check the current config with `sudo iptables -L`. That will print the current set of rules.

Comment: ok Thanks for that information, actually Iam having 2 systems and both are connected to the same network. I intend to send UDP frames from one system to another. For this iam using netcat. On one system iam running the following command nc -luv 6872 and the system starts listening to this port and on the second system i run the command nc -4u -w10 127.0.0.1 6872, when i enter some data on either side I do not see it on the receiver side. Iam running ubuntu on both sides, I would like to know if I am doing something grossly wrong as Iam not into networking. Thanks !!